# Greasemonkey does not recognize and can't install local scripts

Tags: firefox, installation, greasemonkey

I can't install new `*.user.js` local scripts. I use Firefox 11.0, and Greasemonkey 0.9.18.

When I open (Firefox - File - Open) a `.user.js` file on my local disk, it is not recognized as a Greasemonkey user script.

However, if I enter a URL to a `.user.js` file, it is recognized and installed by Greasemonkey.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things that can cause this:

1. Is the script in the system's `temp` path? (as reported by running `echo %temp%` on a Windows command line.)
   There is an unreported "feature" whereby scripts will not install from this location but will install from other folders.
2. Does another script with the same name already exist?
   Uninstall it from the script manager.
3. Firefox's run-time state can get corrupted when debugging scripts, either on a per-tab or program-wide basis.  Try opening a new tab and installing with it focused.
4. Restart like so:

   1. Shut down Firefox.  Use Task Manager to ensure that all Firefox processes are stopped.  They may take a few minutes.  If you use Task Manager to kill a process, it's a good idea to run `CHKDSK` afterwards.
   2. Find the `gm_scripts` folder in your [Firefox profile folder](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/Profiles#w_how-do-i-find-my-profile).
   3. Delete the sub folders for the scripts you were working on and any duplicates or strays that popped up.
   4. Restart Firefox.
   5. Reinstall the GM script(s) you were working on.
5. Follow [the "Bigger Problems" instructions at the GM troubleshooting guide](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Troubleshooting_%28Users%29#Bigger_Problems).

Comment: it was on the TEMP path indeed! Oh how I *love* those little hidden feechures.

Comment: @Brock Adams It did not work for. Even I removed al contents of *gm_scripts* it still opens .js file content.

Comment: @Volatil3, The file must end with `.user.js`.  If you still have a problem after following ***all*** the steps above, open a new question.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the same issue here.
After reading Brock Adams' answer I realized that my folder was named "GM_scripts", so I changed the folder name, tried again and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

uninstalling and installing greasymonkey worked for me. All previous scripts were restored automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Got the same problem with no resolution mentioned here I got my script installed simply by right-clicking the script in a file browser and "opening with ..." the firefox. Script installing dialog popped out and done. No other method working for me at the moment.